# How to debug 20k lines of stored procedure code

Tags: sql, sql-server, debugging, sql-server-2012

I have a stored procedure consists of 19486 lines of code in production environment.

It is difficult to use step in process to debug. Neither can I use any third party tool.

Is there any other way to debug such a lengthy stored procedure?

Comment: generally we debug when there is any error or logic change,is that case?

Comment: @KedarLimaye: exactly both case

Comment: Debugging an SP in a production environment would probably not be a good idea. It could involve locking which could stall production processes. Perhaps altering the procedure to emit logging lines to a specific table you create for that purpose?

Comment: "I have a stored procedure consists of 19486 lines of code " - you should break that insane store proc. up to start with!

Comment: @TT.: I copied SP in Dev, is there any easy way to debug.

Comment: @MitchWheat: :) i break insane Proc, now it is around 400 lines i have to debug. is any smart way to debug and apply change. Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, as TT. already told you, you should avoid debugging on production.

Debugging is not necessarily executing your code line by line. You can also collect information about the execution runtime. This require changes in the code of the procedure. These can be:

- additional `SELECT` clauses to show the contents of temp tables or table variables used in your code
- `PRINT` (or [better](https://www.sqltheater.com/blog/stop-using-print/) `RAISERROR`) statements to track the execution flow and show values of variables
- using `GETDATE()` to measure the time for execution of a code block
- changing the code to make it possible to execute the logic in a separate query window, block by block (like replacing table variables with temp tables, so you can execute a block referencing it separately than the block where it was declared)

And of course, try to break the logic into smaller peaces and to split this monster into few smaller monsters :)

Good lick with debugging!